# SOAP to Rest convertion with collection of items

Tags: rest, soap, wso2-esb

I'm developping a mediation flow in WSO2 Integration Studio. The indbound-endpoint is a rest api and the endpoints is a soap web service.

The client ask for a list of medical specialties.
The backend service respond with this list in SOAP response.
Simply converting SOAP response to JSON with a property mediator is not an option since the client wait for a specific JSON format.

I tried the script mediator without any success. Moreover i read that script mediator should be only used as a last chance solution.

What  is the best practices to do this type of work? (convert soap to json with data collection in it)

SOAP Response is something like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<GetSpecialtiesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetSpecialtiesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WsAgenda.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:Specialty>
<a:code>cardiology</a:code>
<a:name>Cardiologie</a:name>
</a:Specialty>
<a:Specialty>
<a:code>neurology</a:code>
<a:name>Neurologie</a:name>
</a:Specialty>
</GetSpecialtiesResult>
</GetSpecialtiesResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Specific needed REST response format is something like:

```
{
  "specialities": [
    {
      "id": "cardiology",
      "name": "Cardiologie"
    },
    {
      "id": "neurology",
      "name": "Neurologie"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Small clarification: it is obvious that the number of specialties returned is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can convert SOAP to JSON using below 2 properties.

```
<property name="ContentType"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"
               value="application/json"/>
<property name="messageType"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"
               value="application/json"/>
```

Output

```
{ 
   "GetSpecialtiesResponse":{ 
      "GetSpecialtiesResult":{ 
         "Specialty":[ 
            { 
               "code":"cardiology",
               "name":"Cardiologie"
            },
            { 
               "code":"neurology",
               "name":"Neurologie"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i know that i can convert to json with a property mediator. But my problem is to convert to a JSON like:
`
{
  "specialities": [
    {
      "id": "cardiology",
      "name": "Cardiologie"
    },
    {
      "id": "neurology",
      "name": "Neurologie"
    }
  ]
}
`

Comment: You can try Data mapper JSON to JSON

Comment: I tried to user the data mapper. I first convert the soap response with the two properties you give. Next the datamapper do the json to json but without any good result. In the datamapper editor, the sample is working well. But at runtime it gave me an empty </root> result...